# How to add blank UIImageView with certain bounds as a child of UIStackView?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit, xamarin.forms

Can anyone let me know add blank UIImageView with certain height inside the UIStackView?

I cannot add an empty UIImageViews by setting its bounds to the UIStackView. But if we add the UIImage as content for the UIImageView then all the pages are added to the UIStackView which is a child of UIScrollView.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by setting Intrinsic Placeholder size of the UIImageView.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer @Mr.UB
I need to perform this programmatically. Need to add all the Empty UIImageViews inside the StackView from code behind. Is this possible to achieve it programmatically rather than from the design view?

Comment: Glad it helped. Kindly tick mark this answer if it is the exact solution.

Comment: I need to perform this programmatically. Need to add all the Empty UIImageViews inside the StackView from code behind. Is this possible to achieve it programmatically rather than from the design view?

Comment: Sorry, no experience with programatically, I'll update if i find so.